# Exclude form field when calling form from view

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an image upload form that takes a title and a file for its field.  I have two uses for it.  Most of the time I call it, I need both a title and the image itself.  But when I call it simply to grab a thumbnail, I don't need the title.  In fact, the form data is saved to a different model that doesn't even have title as a field.

Is there a way to suppress the "title" field when I call the form?  I could create two form classes in my forms.py, but this seems unnecessarily repetitious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a constructor for the form class

```
def __init__ (self, show_title=True):
    super (BaseClass, self).__init__()
    if not show_title:
        del self.fields['title']
```

Comment: This works great except for one thing.  Now I'm getting validation errors: "This field is required" whether I suppress the title field or not.  Any time I try to submit the form, it tells me I need to enter data.